# What does "humbling enterprise" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

So I've got this sentence while watching a video:

*"Astronomy is a* **humbling enterprise** *to pursue.*"

I couldn't understand what he wanted to mean by "humbling enterprise".

I want an explanation and usage of this phrase.

https://youtu.be/9W3RsaWuCuE?t=3

Comment: I would understand the sentence you provided as "Astronomy involves stuff that would humiliate you in the process"

Comment: Have you looked the words up in a dictionary? What did you find? Are you still puzzled?

Comment: Yes I have used Lexico Oxford.No clue.

Comment: [correction: What does "humbling enterprise" mean? What does x mean?] Please correct your questions and I will remove this comment. You need to look up the transitive verb: to humble and the word enterprise.

Comment: According to Lexico Oxford Humble means cause some to feel not important.What that implies that Astronomy is less important business to pursue. Does that sounds correct?

Comment: @Ghost No, it mean that astronomy provides a perspective that makes an individual feel less self-important. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you've found in Lexico; could you please [edit] this into the question? Comments are temporary and may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right there in the video: 
"Astronomy is a humbling enterprise. After all, every time we make a new discovery, **we find ourselves further removed from importance**."

[American Heritage Dictionary "humble" 1](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=humble)
"1. Marked by meekness or modesty in behavior, attitude, or spirit; not arrogant or prideful."

That is an antonym of "self-important".

The meaning is simply that astronomy discloses to the student the true immensity of the universe, allowing them to see that they are less important in comparison to it.